# Module not found when importing JSX file off github using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, jsx, node-modules

I'm struggling with a "module not found" error off a relative import. I'm trying to implement this github project: https://github.com/cvdlab/react-planner

I've created a new create-react-app project and npm installed the project (react-planner). The readme file calls for downloading the "demo catalog" which contains the following file structure:

> ```
> > catalog
>   > areas
>   > holes
>   > items
>   > lines
>   > utils
>   > mycatalog.js
> ```

mycatalog.js contains the following:

> ```
> import * as Areas from "./areas/**/planner-element.jsx";
> import * as Lines from "./lines/**/planner-element.jsx";
> import * as Holes from "./holes/**/planner-element.jsx";
> import * as Items from "./items/**/planner-element.jsx";
> ```

Upon running (npm start), I get module not found error on each of these imports.

> ```
> ./src/catalog/mycatalog.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve './areas/**/planner-element.jsx' in 'C:\Users\sgola\Desktop\apps\planner\src\catalog'
> ```

These files are definitely located in their respective folders. Catalog folder along with js files are all located in src folder. Public contains only index.html and is located outside of src. I've researched different possible issues from webpack/babel not compiling .jsx files to ** not being recognized as proper path syntax. Nothing is working. I'm at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think relative import should work did you tried import Areas from "./areas/planner-element?

Comment: Still not working, not sure what the issue is at all

Comment: Did you figure it out yet?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [import globals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import-globals) plugin to Your project.

Comment: Describing your solutions and stating it with some code snippet is a better way of answering rather than putting a link only. Would be nice if you add some details to your answers.